# Extra tkinter box when using tkinter with message box

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showinfo("welcome","welcome to piechart creator!!!")
try:
    x=input("enter the file to be fetched:")
    outfile = open(x,"r")
except:
    messagebox.showinfo("alert","enter the file in csv extension!!!")
else:
    file=csv.reader(outfile)
    #skip the headers
    next(file, None)
    row1=input("enter the title of first label:" )
    row2=input("enter the title of label2:")
    row1= []
    row2= []
    for row in file:
        row1.append(row[0])
        row2.append(row[1])
    plt.pie(row2, labels=row1)
    plt.axis('equal')
    messagebox.askyesno("question","do you want the piechart to be created???")
    plt.show()
finally:
    messagebox.showinfo("message","thank you for using piechart creator.")
```

I get an extra tkinter box - why is that?

Comment: Please format your code in a better way, currently we're unable to read any of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly create an instance of `Tk()` tkinter will do this for you. You can fix this by creating the root window explicitly at the beginning of your script, and then hide it:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()     # Create window
root.withdraw()    # Hide window
```